# Content between shortcodes

Tags: shortcode

I am wondering if there is a way to take content between shortcodes and input it into a string, for example, I want to be able to have [shortcode]Hello World![/shortcode] input to a string called $ShortCodeText, how do I do this?

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. It looks like your code got some syntax errors. Can you elaborate what you mean by "content". I wonder if you mean: `[shortcode1]...[/shortcode1] ...GET THIS CONTENT...[shortcode2]...[/shortcode2]` or do you mean something else?

Comment: I edited his post so that the syntax is corrected, just waiting on the edit queue... He May also mean `[shortcode1][shortcode2]Hello Word!![/shortcode2][/shortcode1]`, now that I see your comment... hmmm

Comment: That isnt what a shortcode is for you'll need some custom query's with a date stamp, unless your going to manually input ads with a short code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Example Shortcode:(Taken from: [GenerateWP: Shortcodes Generator](http://generatewp.com/shortcodes/?clone=image-shortcode)

```
// Add Shortcode
function img_shortcode( $atts , $content = null ) {

    // Attributes
    extract( shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'width' => '',
            'height' => '',
        ), $atts )
    );
    // Code
// This is the line you need to study:
return '<img src="' . $content . '" width="' . $width . '" height="' . $height . '">';

}
add_shortcode( 'img', 'img_shortcode' );
```

This is the default [img] tag used by [phpBB](https://www.phpbb.com/) and others as a "shortcut" to posting an image.  Notice that to return HTML you must do it in raw format.  You cannot stack the output across multiple functions, i.e. Pass function 1 to function 2, and expect function 2 to be overloaded with function 1's content.

**UPDATE**

Using the example I gave you earlier, I scribbled this together, I can't promise it will behave the way I expect, nor is there a way to add images except manually:

```
// Add Shortcode
function automatic_ads_shortcode( $atts , $content = null ) {

    // Attributes
    extract( shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'width' => '',
            'height' => '',
        ), $atts )
    );
    // Code
    // Set the $image_array base_dir to the Media Library Path
    define('IMAGES_PATH', dirname(realpath('/wp-content/uploads/')));

    //Ad Rotator 
    //Array of Ads
    //Manually add your ad images to this array. Due
    //to the functionality of a Shortcode, there is no
    //way to accept user input.  You'd need a plugin
    //for that. 
    $image_array = array(IMAGES_PATH . 'img1.jpg',
                         IMAGES_PATH .'img2.jpg',
                         IMAGES_PATH .'img_x.jpg');             
    $current_week = date(W);

    // Shuffling + Random ensures we don't
    // get the same image twice in a row.
    // Every 8 Weeks = 2 months
    if ($current_week % 8 == 0)
    {
        $shuffled_array = shuffle($image_array);
        $chosen_image = array_rand($shufled_array,1);
    }
    //Every 4 Weeks = 1 month
    elseif ($current_week % 4 == 0)
    {
        $shuffled_array = shuffle($image_array);
        $chosen_image = array_rand($shufled_array,1);

    }
    // All other Cases
    else {
        $chosen_image = array_rand($image_array,1); 
    }
//Output Line
return '<img src="' . $chosen_image . '" width="' . $width . '" height="' . $height . '">';

}
add_shortcode( 'auto_ads', 'automatic_ads_shortcode' );
```

After Testing this, use the shortcode [auto_ads] and add said shortcode in the section where the ads normally appear.  As you can see, I stick by the idea that you cannot stack output.

Comment: Why Not use an [Ad Plugin](http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/what-are-the-best-ad-management-plugins-and-solutions-for-wordpress/)?

Comment: I'll help you, if you rephrase your question above and we can do this with a shortcode

Comment: The question has been rephrased

Comment: @User I think this will do the trick

Comment: Thanks for the +1, but please test it 1st... if it's broken, get in touch here, and we'll fix it

Comment: Hi, I keep going back to my code, do you mind telling me, what am I doing wrong here? (Everything works except it does not seem to show the string $contenttext1 or $contenttext2) http://pastebin.com/mn6TG1fR

Comment: You arent returning the string... Look Here [Shortcode Generator](http://generatewp.com/shortcodes/?clone=image-shortcode), which states "Custom code to generate the output.
Should only "return" the text, never produce the output directly."

Comment: if the switch succeeds create a string, ie, `$success="test"`, then underneath the switch `$contenttext1 == $success`, then `return $contenttext1`

Comment: ok, decided not to have a separate function but to have two switch statements under each function, http://pastebin.com/8wcmk1bf This seems to work

Comment: Great!! Glad I could help.